# SQL window function order by v.s. partition by. What are the difference?

Tags: sql, window-functions

I am doing a project that asks the following: "Let’s start by looking at how the average temperature changes over time in each state. Write a query that returns the state, year, tempf or tempc, and running_avg_temp (in either Celsius or Fahrenheit) for each state. (The running_avg_temp should use a window function.)"

The data looks like this: [data schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ROYLc.png)

I wrote 2 types of codes as followed and they seem to perform identically.

My question is how does `order by 1, 2` and `partition by 1 order by 2` differ?

**Solution 1:**

```
SELECT state, year, tempc, 
AVG(tempc) OVER(
    PARTITION BY state
    ORDER BY year
  ) AS 'running_avg_temp'
  FROM state_climate;
```

**Solution 2:**

```
  SELECT state, year, tempc, 
  AVG(tempc) OVER(
    ORDER BY state, year
  ) AS 'running_avg_temp'
  FROM state_climate;
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is significant.  With `partition by`, the average is calculated for each `state` and accumulated by year.

Without `partition by`, the average is for *all* states up to a given state.  So Wyoming (if these are US states) would have the average for basically all states.

You can easily visualize this:

```
state    year   temp   avg-partition   avg-nopartition
  A        1     10        10                10
  A        2     20        15                15
  B        1     30        30                20
```

With the `partition by`, the average starts over again for each state.